neovim doesn't load lsp for some reason
I'm new to Neovim.
I used Kickstart.nvim as a starting point. didn't modify it.
I looked through :checkhealth and fixed almost everything (except some mason stuff related to languages that I'm not using. lua is not one of them.)
but I don't get autocomplete or formatting. and when I load a file (for example, the init.lua file) I get an error telling me:
r/neovim - neovim doesn't load lsp for some reason
client lua_ls quit with exit code 1 and signal 0. so I go to the lsp.log files and I see this error:
[ERROR][2024-08-19 15:18:27] .../vim/lsp/rpc.lua:770"rpc""C:\\Users\\צבי\\AppData\\Local\\nvim-data\\mason\\bin\\lua-language-server.CMD""stderr""The system cannot find the path specified.\r\n"

I've checked. I have the Lua-language-server.CMD file inside mason/bin. I also have stylua. I don't know why the system cannot find the path.
also tried it with other languages then lua. didn't work.
I am usually able to deal with this kind of problems by myself. this is so frustrating... 
don't know why I don't leave it like that and go back to vscode. the power of the hype is real. 
